# "Allow Local Notification" Alert is not coming second time in iOS 8 iphone App

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

In order to use local notifications in the app , we need to get the user permission using 'registerUserNotificationSettings' method which will ask for an alert "Allow Local notifications". For my application, First time it is showing the alert. But if we delete the app from the device and build it again it is not asking agin. I am using iOS 8 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For show alert second time you need to Reset your device or simulator. And also you can On and Off anytime from settings.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. In iOS 7 it is showing the alert we if install the app agin.